# Creating a copy/simulation of a dataset respecting statistical properties?

Tags: data-transformation, dataset

I often need to work with and analyse electronic medical record data which cannot be moved from the servers in the organisation where it resides, due to ethical reasons. Is anyone aware of a method or approach that could create a copy/simulation of the (large) data which respects the statistical properties of original dataset, but where the values of variables are simulated. This would allow a simulated copy could then be used locally to work out analysis coding before applying the the 'real' data? I guess kind of like multiple imputation but for the entire dataset. Is it even possible?
 I maybe should explain further that the purpose of the data copy is to work out data handling and analysis  code  (R, SAS, etc) then take that to the real data. Not to make inference from the copy.
UPDATE
Maybe it's a case of suggesting an approach. Could multiple imputation be adapted to impute everything?  Or maybe data mining techniques to first reduce Colinear variables to single  component?

Comment: What about replacing all _user identifiable information_ with dummy values (or using a specific _coding scheme_)? Would that approach allow you to have/move copies of EMR data sets?

Comment: Ethical considerations (the possibility to identify patients) are very strict. It would not be possible to preserve 'real' combination of data even if ID's had been changed. So the only approach would be a complete simulation of the set. So that no combination of variables could be regarded as real.

Comment: If "statistical properties" means univariate characteristics such as mean and standard deviation, replicating that is a lot easier to accomplish than replicating bivariate or multivariate relationships using simulated values.

Comment: I guess it means multivariate and univariate properties, otherwise it might be difficult to specify analysis approaches. It may of course be impossible!!!

Comment: @AndyC: I see. Thank you for clarification. Is such strictness per HIPAA?

Comment: Hello,  data must be anonymised. But requirements of data owners/ custodians  differ. Some data owners will not allow third parties to analyse the data but will do requested analysis for a fee. Unfortunately they are often very bad at this technically and very slow. E.g. 220% of people are male!!. My question is motivated from that.

Comment: You don't really need to reproduce many statistical characteristics, do you?  For your purposes--to "work out...code"--you just need any kind of data of the right types and domains.  Or do you have some secondary objectives which haven't been stated yet?

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what other motive there could be? It's my job to analyse such data, I am an epidemiologists. This approach would save a lot of time and expense and improve quality of results. It's done with full scientific and ethical approval otherwise you would not get any where near the (anonymised) data. Patients who's data is present is fully consented. I would need to know enough statistical properties to be able to correctly specify statistical approaches and check assumptions of any tests. We need to understand the risk factors for diseases to help combat them.